# Couldn't complete queries in the new flutter firebasefirestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried running this code to get the values stored in an Object in FirebaseFirestore. But didn't get any output.

Could anyone help me with getting Specific fields from the Firestore database?

> String val = FirebaseFirestore.instance
> .collection('users')
> .doc("$userId")
> .get()
> .toString();

val returned

> Closure: () => Map<String,dynamic> from Funtion 'data':.

I also tried adding fieldpath ("displayName" and displayName) to get. Both show error.

Answer (score 2):

All queries for Firestore are essentially **asynchronous**.

The return type of the `get()` function is a **Future**.

To get the actual value, you should wait for the asynchronous call to complete, and then you will have the data to work with.

Something like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.doc("$userId")
.get()
.then()((DocumentSnapshot data) {
    print(data);
    print(data['displayName');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now!